# WCF/REST - System.ServiceModel.Activation

Tags: wcf, rest, mono

Is there anyone who can help me?
The fact:

- I'm using Mono 2.10.9
- I'm building a WCF-REST based WebService
- I need System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceRoute
- That class is contained in System.ServiceModel.Activation assembly
- I don't have the assembly on my linuxbox apparently

Thank you for your time

Comment: This class is not implemented in Mono.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? `System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceRoute` is used to add a route to a WCF service / endpoint when it's running under IIS / ASP.NET. Would a self-hosted service work for you? If so, you don't need that class.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. What I needed was to port a IIS Hosted WCF service under xsp-fastcgi with nginx / But if that isn't possible due to unimplemented class I'll try to document myself on how to build self-hosted services under Mono - that may work I suppose. Thank you!